# Unable to club data from same date in array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object which gets populated from database.

```
dataObj = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Tuesday",
    },

    {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Tuesday",
    },
    {
        "id": "kGSykTUAd6gcEUmskMu6",
        "date": "Wed Nov 08 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Wednesday",
    },
   
]
```

Now I want the UI to be like this-

[image: UI design]

The common date is shown as one date on the left and other information on the right.
For example,
First two entries fall on the same date,
so the left should show one date i.e. Nov 7 and the right section should show all id, month, day for Nov 7.

But when I'm comparing the array and converting the duplicate dates as one and then displaying the date, it does not show the right output. The output is -

Nov 7 - id, date, month

Nov 7 - id, date, month

**Correct Output should be**

```
   Nov 7  

   id, date, month

   id, date, month

   Nov 8

   id, date, month
```

JS

```
let datesArr = []

// Pushing the data in the array.
datesArr.push( doc.data().dates )

// Removing same dates from the datesArr
let duplicates = datesArr.filter( function ( item, index, inputArray )
    {
        return inputArray.indexOf( item ) === index
    } )

    duplicates.sort( ( a, b ) =>
    {
        return a - b
    } )

    for ( let dupes of duplicates )
    {
        let myArr = []
        let dupesDate = new Date( dupes ).toDateString()

        for ( let content of dataObj)
        {
            if ( dupesDate === new Date( content.date).toDateString() )
            {
                myArr.push( content );
            }
        }
        
    }
```

How do I fix this, I been struggling with this for few days now.

Comment: So you need data in this format, 
[{"date":"Tue Nov 07 2023","items":[{"id":"1","date":"Tue Nov 07 2023","month":"11","day":"Tuesday"},{"id":"2","date":"Tue Nov 07 2023","month":"11","day":"Tuesday"}]},{"date":"Wed Nov 08 2023","items":[{"id":"kGSykTUAd6gcEUmskMu6","date":"Wed Nov 08 2023","month":"11","day":"Wednesday"}]}]

??

Comment: yes, that's the right format.

Comment: I have added my code snippet in answer below

Comment: What are you trying to push here ```datesArr.push( doc.data().dates )```? ```doc``` is missing in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet to convert it into your expected output,

```
const dataObj = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Tuesday",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Tuesday",
    },
    {
        "id": "kGSykTUAd6gcEUmskMu6",
        "date": "Wed Nov 08 2023",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "Wednesday",
    },
];

const dateWiseObject = {};

dataObj.forEach(item => {
    const date = item.date;
    if (!dateWiseObject[date]) {
        dateWiseObject[date] = [];
    }
    dateWiseObject[date].push(item);
});

const container = document.getElementById("container");

for (const date in dateWiseObject) {
    const items = dateWiseObject[date];
    const dateObj = new Date(date);
    const month = dateObj.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
    const day = dateObj.getDate();

    const header = document.createElement("div");
    header.textContent = `${month} ${day}`;
    container.appendChild(header);

    items.forEach(item => {
        const itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        itemDiv.textContent = `id: ${item.id}, date: ${item.date}, month: ${item.month}`;
        itemDiv.style.padding = "10px"; // Add padding to the inner child elements
        container.appendChild(itemDiv);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working but the UI is not coming as desired.

 for ( let res of resultArray )
    {
        let datesContent = `<div>${ res.date }</div>`;
        for ( let item of res.items )
        {
            console.log( item.appointmentDate, item.appointmentName );
            let detailsContent = `<div>${ item.appointmentDate }, ${ item.appointmentName }</div>`
            details.innerHTML += detailsContent
        }
        dates.innerHTML += datesContent
    }

After making the changes, it is not rendering the way it should. It is just showing the data.

Comment: Can you check it now, I have updated my answer with some demo UI

Comment: Updated code will return you same output as you expected, you can make style changes as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```js
const dataObj = [{
    "id": "1",
    "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Tuesday",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Tuesday",
  },
  {
    "id": "kGSykTUAd6gcEUmskMu6",
    "date": "Wed Nov 08 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Wednesday",
  },
];

// Group data by date
const groupedData = dataObj.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const dateStr = new Date(obj.date).toDateString();
  if (!acc[dateStr]) {
    acc[dateStr] = [];
  }
  acc[dateStr].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

const app = document.getElementById("app");

for (const date in groupedData) {
  const dateGroup = document.createElement("div");
  dateGroup.classList.add("date-group");

  const dateElement = document.createElement("div");
  dateElement.classList.add("date");
  dateElement.textContent = date;
  dateGroup.appendChild(dateElement);

  for (const item of groupedData[date]) {
    const itemElement = document.createElement("div");
    itemElement.textContent = `id: ${item.id}, month: ${item.month}, day: ${item.day}`;
    dateGroup.appendChild(itemElement);
  }

  app.appendChild(dateGroup);
}
```

```css
.date-group {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.date {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating intermediate variables (constants) and DOM objects and `append`ing them together you could also do it with a single `.innerHTML` assignment. The simplified algorithm for grouping below will work if gigs with the same date appear consecutively. Knowing that the data is taken from a database this condition can be easily achieved by sorting by date.

```js
const dataObj = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Tuesday",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": "Tue Nov 07 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Tuesday",
  },
  {
    "id": "kGSykTUAd6gcEUmskMu6",
    "date": "Wed Nov 08 2023",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "Wednesday",
  }
];

//grouping the data by 'date'
const grp = dataObj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc.last?.[0]?.date==curr.date) {
    // 'date' already exists: add the current object to the acc.last array:
    acc.last.push(curr);
  } else {
    // create a new array in acc:
    acc.push(acc.last=[curr]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
// console.log(grp);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = grp.map(gigs =>
    `<div><h3>${gigs[0].date}</h3><ul>`
    +gigs.map(gig => `<li>${Object.values(gig).join(", ")}</li>`).join("\n")+"</ul>").join("\n")+"</div>";
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```